# How to Change color theme in powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, colors, themes, templates

I am having some problem with my PowerPoint Templates, I have 2 Files A & B. Both ppt files are having segmented many 2D / 3D shapes in it (like pyramids, arrows, loops etc.) some thing like infographics.

**Now in file A, when I go to PowerPoint > Design tab > Variants > Drop down arrow > Color > Slide theme Color & then changes color theme or color environment of whole slide changes automatically.**

**But in file B, when I do same thing, nothing happens to slide, and I have to change by selecting each segment of shape.**

Is there is any method that when it will automatically change all color theme in one click just like in slide A. Many thanks in advance.
Here, I am attaching 50 KB sample having 2 slides of both files, in this PowerPoint file

[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ciqo0TXZYnmc82d8Y8jafF6HSwpE34AF/view?usp=sharing][1]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the colors in the B slides are not theme colors, they're chosen from Other colors (ie, they're RGB colors, not theme colors). You'd have to select each shape and assign it fill/line/gradient colors from the theme palette in order to "put it back on the theme".  After that, the colors will change when you change themes.